# I am currently running Linux Mint 18.1 Cinammon 64 bit.

Tags: linux-mint

I have installed  Software update center , But when i try to open it it does not open.Please help. I have tried reinstalling it but it is of no use. The problem still persists. I have dual booted linux mint with win 10.

Comment: Consider changing the title of the question to reflect the problem.  Running Mint isn't a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Software Update Center to install apps. Open terminal and type

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install <program name>
```